# What's meaning of -print0 in following command

Tags: linux, shell

I am using following command in Mac to replace string. 
Here I have a question about -print0. What's usage of it?

```
find skeleton/src/IO.Swagger/Controllers -name '*.cs'  -print0| xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/namespace IO.Swagger.Controllers/namespace Abc.GroupA.TableLocalService.Controllers/g"
```

Comment: From `man find`: *"-print0
              True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline character that -print uses).  This allows
              file  names  that  contain  newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output.  This option
              corresponds to the -0 option of xargs."* In this case `xargs` is processing the `find` output and the `print0` insures that it correctly processes even files named with garbage like a newline character.

Comment: Like any other argument to a command, it's meant to push people to read the manual :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With `-print0`, `find` will separate the filenames with a null character (a zero byte). `xargs` must then be called with `-0` (or `--null`, I recommend using long options in scripts, which increase readability, and reserve shortenings for disposable commands in an interactive console).

This way, you can use spaces or whatever characters, including new-lines, in the filenames.

Answer (score 4):

It means "You probably want `-exec` instead."

```
sed_script="s/namespace IO.Swagger.Controllers/namespace Abc.GroupA.TableLocalService.Controllers/g"

find skeleton/src/IO.Swagger/Controllers -name '*.cs'  -print0 |
  xargs -0 sed -i "" "$sed_script"
```

becomes

```
sed_script="s/namespace IO.Swagger.Controllers/namespace Abc.GroupA.TableLocalService.Controllers/g"

find skeleton/src/IO.Swagger/Controllers -name '*.cs' \
  -exec sed -i "" "$sed_script" {} \;
```